# Display several user blog entries at once

Tags: 7, nodes

I use Blog 7.7 core module to display site updates at http://preferans.de/blog/1

However only 1 news item is always displayed at that link.

Is there maybe a way to change that amount?

I've tried looking around, including **admin/content/book/settings**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create a "[view](http://drupal.org/project/views)" to display a list of blogs. In Views you can specify how to layout those blogs, how many to show, in what order, etc.
NoneOne has a great [screencast about learning views](http://nodeone.se/blogg/taming-the-beast-learn-views-with-nodeone-0)